# How to avoid cyclic dependencies while implementing infix operators

Tags: matrix, vector, f#, operators, static-methods

Let's assume that I wish to implement a Vector and a Matrix class in F#. The language disallows cyclic dependencies, so I can't have both the Vector class referencing the Matrix class and vice versa. Let's furthermore say that I make the choice that neither of the classes should depend on the other (in contrast to the case where e.g. Vector depends Matrix but not the other way around).

Now I'd like to implement right-multiplication of a Matrix instance with a Vector instance, i.e. a * b where a is a Matrix and b is a Vector. A first thought would be to declare op_Multiply as a static member method in for example the Matrix class. In C#, this would mean having a static method with a signature like this

```
public static Vector operator *(Matrix matrix, Vector vector);
```

on e.g. the Matrix class. However, this operation depends both on the Vector class and on the Matrix class, and so cannot be declared in neither the Matrix nor the Vector class, since these are not allowed to depend on one another.

A next thought might be to declare it as some sort of extension method, in F# something to the effect of:

```
[<Extension>]
static member (*) (matrix : IMatrix, vector : IVector) =
    ...
```

However, this merely allows me to write something like

```
a.op_Multiply(b)
```

and not

```
a * b
```

The problem here, in a sense, is that I can't write "operator extension methods". How can I define the multiplication method such that I avoid having Matrix and Vector depend on each other while also achieving the ability to write something like "a * b"?

Comment: First, F# does allow circular dependencies in a small context. You can totally make `Vector` and `Matrix` reference each other if you choose so. Second, to define an operator on previously defined types, make it a free-standing function, not a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can write operators as `let`-bound functions in modules with the `[<AutoOpen>]` attribute:

```
module Foo =
    type Bar = Bar of string

module Ploeh =
    type Fnaah = Fnaah of string

[<AutoOpen>]
module Operators =
    let (+) (Foo.Bar b) (Ploeh.Fnaah f) = b + f

open Foo
open Ploeh

let sum = (Bar "sgryt") + (Fnaah "ler")
```

This, at least, produces the expected output in FSI:

```
> let sum = (Bar "sgryt") + (Fnaah "ler");;    
val sum : string = "sgrytler"
```

It's not something I do often, so I can't say if there are some corner cases that would make this work less ideal in practice...